# UDP Proxy in Golang

Tags: go, udp

I am trying to create an UDP Proxy in Go without success.

My objective is to get the DNS response from a server and write it back to the client.

```
$ kdig -d @0.0.0.0:8853 facebook.com

n, client, err := u.server.ReadFromUDP(buf) // read request

n, err = u.server.WriteToUDP(buf, client)  // write it back
```

Should i be doing something different? Response:

```
WARNING: response timeout for 0.0.0.0@8853(UDP)
```

PS: My TCP Implementation works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: 0.0.0.0 may select the public network interface, which is subject to firewalling. What happens if you use 127.0.0.1 instead?

Comment: kdig -d @127.0.0.1:8853 facebook.com ? 

The same timeout happens